# TextViews getting stacked

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build a tinder-like feature on android studio using java. Each slide has a video (that can played) and some TextViews that represent the user's name, age, etc. However, the TextViews are getting stacked on all slides except on the last slide.

See how the TextViews look like on all slides except the last one:

[image]

What might be wrong?

Here is my model:

```
public class Person {

    private String videoLink;
    private String place;
    private String name;
    private String payment;
    private String age;

    public Person(String videoLink, String place, String name, String payment, String age) {
        this.videoLink = videoLink;
        this.place = place;
        this.name = name;
        this.payment = payment;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getPlace(){
        return place;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public String getVideoLink() {
        return videoLink;
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity file:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;
import com.xxxx.xxxxx.models.Person;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindDateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingAdapterView;
    private VideoAdapter videoAdapter;

    private TextView name;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView paying;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_date);

        flingAdapterView=findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "All hands Memorial College, New York", "Rick", "Together", "24"));
        persons.add(new Person(("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "KingFisher Restaurant", "James", "Together", "45"
        ));
        persons.add(new Person(("https://xxxxxxxxx.mp4", "The Place Restaurant", "Angel", "Separately", "33"
        ));
//
        videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(persons);
        flingAdapterView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

        flingAdapterView.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                if (videoAdapter.getCount() != 0) {
                   videoAdapter.remove(videoAdapter.getItem(0));
                    videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object o) {

                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(-1); // Stop playback when card is swiped left
                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(FindDateActivity.this,"dislike",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object o) {
                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(-1);
                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(FindDateActivity.this,"like",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float v) {

            }
        });

        flingAdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int i, Object o) {
                videoAdapter.setCurrentPosition(i);
               
            }
        });



        Button like,dislike;

        like=findViewById(R.id.like);
        dislike=findViewById(R.id.dislike);

        like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentPosition = flingAdapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Get the current selected position
                if (currentPosition != SwipeFlingAdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    flingAdapterView.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
                }
            }
        });

        dislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentPosition = flingAdapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); // Get the current selected position
                if (currentPosition != SwipeFlingAdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    flingAdapterView.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

        private int currentPosition = -1;
        VideoAdapter(List<Person> persons) {
            super(FindDateActivity.this, 0, persons);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            }

            FrameLayout frameLayout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoContainer);
            frameLayout.removeAllViews(); // Remove any previous VideoView

            VideoView videoView = new VideoView(getContext());
            videoView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            Person person = getItem(position);
            if (person != null) {
                String videoUrl = person.getVideoLink();
                if (videoUrl != null) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
                    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

                    TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
                    TextView addressTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
                    TextView payingTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPaying);

                    nameTextView.setText(person.getName());
                    addressTextView.setText(person.getPlace());
                    payingTextView.setText(person.getPayment());



                    // You can also set up media controller if needed
                    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                    // Set a callback for when the video is prepared to start playing
                    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            if (position == currentPosition) {
                                videoView.start();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    videoView.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            frameLayout.addView(videoView);

            return convertView;
        }
        public void setCurrentPosition(int position) {
            currentPosition = position;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_find_date.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dislike"
            android:text="dislike"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="like"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/like"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/line1"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.0"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="337dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- TextViews outside the video FrameLayout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoContainer"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPaying"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item.xml` doesn't have a background, that's why you can see other `TextView`s behind.

Please try specifying `android:background="@android:color/white"` (or any background you like) to the root of the `item.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintLayout, Adjust your layout as you like by giving padding, margin and your desired color

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="337dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<!-- TextViews outside the video FrameLayout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/videoContainer"
    android:text="TextView2"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoContainer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewName"
    android:text="TextView3"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPaying"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewAddress"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewAddress" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```